# How to run an uninstaller from an outdated .dmg?

Tags: macos, driver

I figured recently that I don't get LAN from from Kensington SD1500 box. It turns out it needs its own driver on macOS. So I downloaded the corresponding zip file from [Kensington](https://az31609.vo.msecnd.net/software/f6887d17-45f7-483d-9de5-d937d0b3605a.zip).

I went through the installer, but it seems it is too old and not accepted. So although the installation passed, after the restart, "Disabled software" shows that driver as disabled, because "missing user consent".

I wanted to at least *uninstall* that thing. Opened the .dmg that comes with the above zip file, but when I click the corresponding "uninstall command" file, I get:

> “AX88179_178A_Uninstall_v1.6.0.command” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.

Any idea how I can remove the installed (disabled driver)?

Comment: Have you looked at the Apple article on the issue? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchleab3a043/mac

Answer (score 2):

1. In a Finder window, double click on the disk image to reveal its contents.
2. Secondary click on the `AX88179_178A_Uninstall_v1.6.0.command` file, (i.e. either press and hold the <kbd>Control</kbd> key and click or do a two finger tap on file icon) to reveal the Finder context menu. Click on the **Open** command.

   [image]
3. In the dialogue box that's presented, click the **Open** button.

   [image]

Comment: Yeah, this probably works. But then: I opened the file in an editor, and saved as shell script, and ran that directly from the command line. It gets to the last print that says "uninstall successful", but alas, there were also some warnings printed before, and after reboot, the device driver still shows up. So, your answer is perfectly fine, it is just that ... running that script actually doesn't do what it is supposed to do ;-(

Comment: I use the same driver myself and can attest that both install and uninstall work fine. I am currently running Big Sur and have also used it with both Mojave and Catalina in the past. Just make sure to run the script from within the DMG.

Comment: Well, it is just a script. I just ran it from the .dmg, same thing: some warnings, it gets to the final print ... but after a restart, the device driver still shows up in the "disabled software" section.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the output you get from Terminal into the question?